# Run perl script as a windows service

Tags: windows, perl, service

How do you run a perl script as a windows service?

I have a script that gathers all sort of data and then relays them to a server, but I need to run this as a system service in order to report data all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the procedure descibed on this page:

[Install a perl script as a Win NT/2000/XP service.](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=230377)

> This perl script uses *srvany* and
>   *instsrv* (two free programs from
>   Microsoft; put on my perlmonk.org
>   website for ease of linking) to
>   install a perl script as a Windows
>   NT/2000/XP service.

In the comments on the same page there a some interesting options:

> I prefer to compile my scripts with
>   perl2exe and install the binary as a
>   service. I've used instsrv and srvany,
>   but I prefer to use the freely
>   available FireDaemon.

and

> You might also consider [Win32::Daemon](http://www.roth.net/perl/Daemon/) for a pure-perl solution.

---

As alternative you could also try [ExeService](http://slion.net/view/Dev/ExeService), a program which allows you to run executables, scripts and commands as Windows Services.

Comment: great !
any advantages on using FireDaemon, or Win32::Daemon ???

Comment: well... FireDaemon dosen't seem to be open source, since i am interested in a $$$ less solution :D

Comment: Hmm, Win32::Daemon appears not to be available for current perl versions. See this updated code from the author of the first link:
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=744578

Comment: and perl2exe is a eval version, that inserts a message at the end of my script, as well as a 2sec delay at the end.

Comment: You can also use par instead of perl2exe to create executables of your perl scripts.  (free and available from CPAN)

Comment: Forgot to add the link:  http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PAR-0.992/lib/PAR.pm